# Range-Bounded Commitment fails when implemented?

Tags: hash, java

For part of my thesis I must implement (in Java) a Chan, Frankel, Tsiounis range-bounded commitment protocol as quoted in Boudot's paper [Efficient Proofs that a Committed Number Lies in an Interval](https://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2000/1807/18070437-new.pdf) §1.2.3 which I've quoted below for convenience:

> The main idea of this proof is roughly the same as the one of [2]. Let $t$, $l$, and $s$ be three security parameters. This protocol (due to Chan, Frankel, and Tsiounis [7], and corrected in [8], and also due to [14] in another form) proves that a committed number in $x \in I$ belongs to $J$, where the expansion rate $\#J/\#I$ is equal to $2^{t+l+1}$. Let $n$ be a large composite number whose factorization is unknown by Alice and Bob, $g$ be an element of large order in $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{n}$ and $h$ be an element of the group generated by $g$ sucht hat both the discrete logarithm of $g$ in bade $h$ and the discrete logarithm of $h$ in base $g$ are unknown by Alice. Let $H$ be a hash-function which outputs $2t$-bit strings. We denote by $E=E(x,r)=g^{x}h^{r}\mod n$ a commitment to $x \in [0,b]$, where $r$ is randomly selected over $[-2^{s}n+1,2^{s}n-1]$. This commitment, from [13], statistically reveals no information about $x$ to Bob.
>
> **Protocol:** $PK_{[CFT]}(x,r: E=E(x,r) \wedge x \in [-2^{t+l}b,2^{t+l}b])$.
>
> 1. Alice picks random $\omega \in _{R}[0,2^{t+l}b-1]$ and $\eta \in _{R}[-2^{t+l+s}n+1,2^{t+l+s}n-1]$, and then computes $W=g^{\omega}h^{\eta} \mod n$.
> 2. Then, she computes $C=H(W)$ and $c=C \mod 2^{t}$.
> 3. Finally, she computes $D_{1}= \omega + xc$ and $D_{2}= \eta +rc$ (in $\mathbb{Z}$). If $D_{1} \in [cb,2^{t+l}b-1]$, she sends $(C,D+{1},D_{2})$ to Bob, otherwise she starts again the protocol.
> 4. Bob checks that $D_{1} \in [cb,2^{t+l}b-1]$ and that $C=H(g^{D_{1}}h^{D_{2}}E^{-c})$. This convinces Bob that $x \in [-2^{t+l}b, 2^{t+l}b]$.

I have implemented other protocols in this paper successfully, however in this case I haven't had any success, specifically because Alice's check of $D_{1} \in [cb,2^{t+l}b-1]$ always fails no matter how many times it is retried. I am curious if the logic in the protocol as written is invalid, or if it is something in my code. I've looked over the code for days and had a couple peers review it, and neither have found anything that should be causing this to fail. I've quoted code below.

```
/**
 * Produces a CFT proof as defined in Boudot paper. 
 * @param x The original message committed to in e.
 * @param r The random value in the commitment e of x.
 * @param e The value of the commitment.
 * @param b The bounding value such that x is in [0, b]
 * @param commit Object containing all the FO commitment parameters (e.g. g, h, n) and access to commit()
 * @return An array {C, D1, D2} that satisfies the CFT range-bounded commitment proof.
 */
public static BigInteger[] proofCFT(BigInteger x, BigInteger r, BigInteger e, BigInteger b, FujisakiOkamotoCommitment commit)
{
    SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();

    // Security parameters
    int t = 128; // Because SHA-256 is 256-bit
    int l = rand.nextInt(100);
    int s = rand.nextInt(100);

    // 2^(t+l+s)
    BigInteger tls2 = BigInteger.valueOf(2L).pow(t+l+s);

    // 2^(t+l)*b-1
    BigInteger b2tl_minus1 = BigInteger.valueOf(2L).pow(t+l).multiply(b).subtract(BigInteger.ONE);

    while(true)
    {
        BigInteger omega = getRandomInRange(BigInteger.ZERO, b2tl_minus1); // omega in [0, 2^(t+l)*b-1]
        BigInteger eta   = getRandomInRange( // eta in [-2^(t+l+s)*n+1, 2^(t+l+s)*n-1]
                commit.n().multiply(tls2).negate().add(BigInteger.ONE),
                commit.n().multiply(tls2).subtract(BigInteger.ONE));

        BigInteger w = commit.commit(omega, eta); // g^(omega)*h^(eta) mod n

        byte[] hash = new byte[0];
        try
        {
            hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(w.toByteArray());
        }
        catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae){} // Never occurs

        BigInteger bigC = new BigInteger(1, hash);
        BigInteger littleC = bigC.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(2L).pow(t)); // bigC mod 2^t

        BigInteger d1 = x.multiply(littleC).add(omega); // d1 = omega + xc
        BigInteger d2 = r.multiply(littleC).add(eta);   // d2 = eta + rc

        // Keep going until D1 in [c*b, b*2^(t+l)-1]
        BigInteger lowerBound = b.multiply(littleC);
        if(d1.compareTo(lowerBound) >= 0 && d1.compareTo(b2tl_minus1) <= 0) // Never succeeds??
            return new BigInteger[]{bigC, d1, d2};
    }
}
```

Note that `getRandomInRange(BigInteger max, BigInteger min)` has been thoroughly tested and always uniformly returns a value in that range (inclusive).

Also, `FujisakiOkamotoCommitment` always generates $n$ such that its large prime factors $p$ and $q$ are safe primes.

Comment: unfortunately, the migration has killed TeX rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further testing and research into where this came from, I have determined that it was indeed the algorithm as written that was incorrect. Namely, the original protocol computes $\omega = _{R}[0,2^{b(t+l)}-1]$ and thus the check is $D_{1}\in[cb,2^{b(t+l)}-1]$, and **not** $2^{t+l}b-1$ as the linked paper specifies.

Also incorrect is the line in step 4: $H(g^{D_{1}}h^{D_{2}}E^{-c})$, which should be $H(g^{D_{1}}h^{D_{2}}E^{-c}\mod n)$, which the author may have intended to imply but (in my opinion) should probably have specified.

With these errors in mind, and the corresponding adjustments to the code, the protocol now consistently passes. I am confident in judging this as a misprint in the Boudot paper.